# why does uniform electric field applies only torque on the electric dipole?

Tags: electrostatics

And does the potential remains constant at every point in the uniform electric field?
Because if potential will change then there must be some force appliric dipole ?ed.

Answer (score 1):

Electric dipole is made up of a positively charged particle $+q$ and a negatively charged particle $-q$.

Consider the electric dipole as an whole object in a uniform electric field $E$. 
The **NET** force acting on it would be

\begin{align}
F_{net} = F_{+q} + F_{-q} = (+q)E + (-q)E = 0
\end{align}

Other Remarks:

Recall the definition of potential $V(\vec{r}) = -\int_{\vec{r}_{0} }^{\vec{r}} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$. Thus, for uniform electric field say in $x$ direction, we have
\begin{align}
V(x) = -E(x - x_{0})
\end{align}
So potential in this case is indeed varying spatially in $x$ direction.